# Showing that a proper algebraic subset of $k^1$ is closed iff it's finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, solution-verification

$\newcommand{\scrO}{\mathscr{O}}$
$ \newcommand{\A}{\mathbb{A}}$

**Problem:** A proper subset $X \subset \A^1_k$ is closed if and only if it is finite.

Here the topology being considered is the Zariski topology so the closed sets are exactly the algebraic sets. Here is a proof of the reverse direction from a book.

> We know that if $I$ is a maximal ideal of $\scrO(\A^n)$ that $V(I) = \{p\}$ and so singletons are algebraic sets corresponding to maximal ideals of $\scrO(\A^n)$. Therefore because singletons are closed and as a topology finite unions of closed sets are closed it follows that any finite set is closed.

What I don't understand is why this approach. What I had thought was the following, which seems more intuitive but where is it wrong?

> Let $X = \{x_1,\dots,x_m\}$. Then let $f = \prod_1^m (x-x_i) \in \scrO(\A^1) = k[x]$. Notice that $V(f) = X$ where $V$ denotes the vanishing set of the polynomial. Therefore $X$ is algebraic as it corresponds to the vanishing set of some $f \in k^1$.

Comment: Both approaches are okay; it's not hard to verify that $V(f)\cup V(g) = V(fg)$. Note, however, that the first version proves more: it proves that finite subsets of affine $n$-space are closed, whereas your argument only proves it for $n=1$.

Comment: Also, your approach only works if $k$ is algebraically closed, and you're viewing $x_{1}, \ldots, x_{m}$ as elements of $k$. The approach sketched by whatever book you are using applies even when $k$ is not algebraically closed. That being said, you could fix your approach by using that $k[X]$ is a PID, and then picking generators for each of your prime ideals, taking $f$ to be the product of all of the generators.

Comment: Ah it hadn't appreciated that the first method is stronger. Thanks @ArturoMagidin

Comment: All of my fields are algebraically closed right now, but thanks for the fix @AlexWertheim

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach also works.

In fact if you replace the polynomials $(x - x_i)$ by an ideal defining the point $x_i$ it also generalizes to both of the situations noted in the comments. In general $V(I) \cup V(J) = V(IJ)$. If $X = \mathbb{A}^1$ then $k[X]$ is a PID so all the ideals are principal and if further $k$ is algebraically closed then the only maximal ideals (points) are generated by polynomials of the form $x - x_i$ so in this case it reduces to exactly what you wrote.

Depending on definitions some version of this should be involved in checking that the Zariski topology is a topology, so is also implicit in what the book says.